# How to pass php data on Javascript

Tags: javascript, php, html

Currently I use this code to display the result on the screen

```
$sqlUrl = "SELECT *
            FROM $category
            WHERE sub_category = '$subCategory'";

$result = mysqli_query($con,$sqlUrl);
echo "<ul>";
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
  {
  echo "<li>";
  echo "<a href='$row[url]'>$row[link_text]</a>";
  echo "</li>";
  }
echo "</ul>";
```

but using an other template html file the above code displays the results at the very beginning of the page. So, I have place a div in html template

```
<div id="div6">

</div>
```

and I am to use JScript so as for the results to display at the div place. The script looks like

```
<script>
document.getElementById("div6").innerHTML= "XXXX";
</script>
```

Could you please let me know what to write on the XXXX place?

Comment: If you're using a template, why don't you just edit the template so your PHP output goes inside `#div6`? Using JavaScript to do it just seems like an overkill.

Comment: I had originally tried to do like that but since it is a phpBB board it doesn't permit it...So, that's the reason why to use JScript

Comment: The template is html...if I do it php then the board doesn't work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't have any experience with phpBB, so I can't provide much help with how to use the template, unfortunately. But I recommend that you do more research to figure out how to do it correctly by using the template to display it.

If you really want to go the JavaScript route, you can edit your PHP code to give the `ul` a unique ID, so `echo "<ul>";` would become `echo "<ul id='some-id'>";`, then your JavaScript code should look something like this:

```
document.getElementById('div6').appendChild(document.getElementById('some-id'))‌​;
```

Answer (score 0):

As you have found out, anything echo'd from the php file is displayed before the template is parsed, so you need to assign template variables (or in this case block variables because the output is from a loop).

In your php file:

```
$sqlUrl = "SELECT *
            FROM $category
            WHERE sub_category = '$subCategory'";

$result = mysqli_query($con,$sqlUrl);

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
  {
  $template->assign_block_vars('loopname', array(
    'THE_URL'       => $row[url],
    'THE_LINK_TEXT' => $row[link_text]
  ));
  }
```

then inside your template file:

```
<li>
<!-- BEGIN loopname -->
  <a href="{loopname.THE_URL}">{loopname.THE_LINK_TEXT}</a>
<!-- END loopname -->
</ul>
```